# How do I filter a list of users based on clicking on a chart that is controlled by a parameter?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have a list of users, and I'm tracking when these users have reached certain events.

My user list consists of

- Name
- User Created Date
- User Role (3 types of roles - Engineer, Architect, and Lawyer)
- Email
- Country
- Event 1 (Yes / No)
- Event 1 Date
- Event 2 (Yes / No)
- Event 2 Date
- Event 3 (Yes / No)
- Event 3 Date

I've pulled this data into Tableau, and I want to see what % of users have reached certain events. In order to get this metric, I've created 3 calculated fields (for the 3 events) thats like this:

[image]

The x-axis is the User Created Date (displayed as month), and the y-axis is percentage. I'm using 'User Role' under Color

I've created a Parameter and a Filter as such:

[image]

[image]

I've created a dashboard displaying the chart and user list. When I click on a specific data point, I'd like to see only those users who are Event  = 'Yes'

[image]

Really appreciate the help!